# code 42803 in my postgresql query.getting aggregate function error

Tags: sql, postgresql

in my query where is my mistake?

```
SELECT okuyucu,mac,rssi FROM etiketokuyucu where rssi<0 and mac='aaaa' group by etiketokuyucu.okuyucu ORDER BY etiketokuyucu.rssi desc LIMIT 3
```

I am getting an error about sql state: 42803

thank you for your help

Comment: I think it's a group by error caused by okuyucu,mac,rssi.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you can fix it by putting them all under group by.

Comment: this cannot solve my problem because it isnot a group function

Comment: For an answer, you need to tell us what the query is supposed to do. It makes no sense as it is now (which is why you get the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not aggregating any values there is no point in using `group by` in the query. This will just provide you `unique` values. Instead you can remove `group by` and just use `distinct` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT okuyucu, mac, rssi
FROM etiketokuyucu 
WHERE rssi < 0 AND mac = 'aaaa' 
ORDER BY rssi desc
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
      okuyucu 
      ,mac
      ,rssi
FROM 
      etiketokuyucu 
WHERE 
      rssi < 0 
AND 
      mac = 'aaaa'
GROUP BY
      1
ORDER BY 
      3 
LIMIT 
      3
```

without seeing any of the actual data it's hard to know what the issue is for sure.  My guess is that you have data in the other two fields that also need to be grouped if this still throws an error.

You can try moving it to the end:

```
SELECT 
       mac
      ,rssi
      ,okuyucu
FROM 
      etiketokuyucu 
WHERE 
      rssi < 0 
AND 
      mac = 'aaaa'
GROUP BY
      3
ORDER BY 
      3 
LIMIT 
      3
```

However, this may not achieve whatever results you are looking for.